# How can I disable the F1 help in gnome-terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, gnome

I use the gnome-terminal (terminal from the launcher) on my "Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS." Frequently, I am typing along thinking about what I am typing, not the environment and I accidentally hit the F1 key and up comes  a window that says "Terminal Help." Please, I don't need help (at least with the terminal).

Is there any way to disable the gnome terminal help screen?

I would prefer if I hit F1 by accident, it just ignored me.  I seem to recall turning off the blinking cursor with some sort of X setting a while ago but at this point, I have no recollection of what I did or where. Is  there something similar to disable the F1 or Help screen?  If there is not a way to disable F1 in gnome term, is there a way to disable F1 all together (besides pulling off the key-cap)?  It is probably used in some applications I don't use so I would be happy if it went away.

Answer (score 7):

In `GNOME Terminal` go to Edit -> Preferences -> Shortcuts and scroll to the bottom. You'll see <kbd>F1</kbd> being bound to Help there. Double click on it, then press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to unbind.

Comment: Thanks.  That did what was required, mostly. When I hit escape after the double click, it went back to F1 so I set it to Alt-F8, something I don't expect to type accidentally anytime soon.

Comment: Oops, my bad. Press Backspace to unbind. I've updated the answer.